# What is the proper way to redirect http requests based on the content in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

While running an express server, what is the proper way to redirect incoming requests?

I have two routes: POST and UPDATE. The POST route is used to create new item to database and UPDATE increases votes in the item.

I would like to use middleware(?) to redirect my requests based on db content:

- **if** element with req.param does exist => redirect to UPDATE to handle upvotes
- **else** create new element => redirect to POST to handle creation

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way of doing this could be:

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
     req.param.name ? req.url = '/POST' : req.url = '/UPDATE' 
          next();
}
```

, Or you can redirect your request to other routes.

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
     req.param.name ? res.redirect('/POST') : res.redirect(/UPDATE')
          next();
}
```

Also, you can make dynamic routes if you have many routes involved doing different things. You can check this: [How to call an api from another api in expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903053/how-to-call-an-api-from-another-api-in-expressjs)